# 36 year old no frost refrigerator has stopped heating. Is it worth tracking problem and fixing or is replacement the most economical option?

Tags: refrigerator

36 year old no frost refrigerator has stopped heating.  Is it worth tracking problem and fixing or is replacement the most economical option?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be cooling?

Comment: Fix it and get it heating again. Wait a minute, remind me why are we heating the house with the refrigerator?

Answer (score 5):

Replace it. Modern refrigerators are so much more energy-efficient that you'll probably recoup the purchase price in a few years.

Comment: Unless it is an ammonia absorption cycle refrigerator, those are collector items.

Comment: Good point. In that case you can sell it to a collector, pick up a new energy-efficient fridge, and probably come away with cash in your pocket.